# Ionic3 background-image from variable

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I am using ngFor to output an array of posts. Each should have a background image.
getBackgroundStyle extracts the URL of the image from the post (which is an array)

```
    <div class="singlePost" *ngFor="let post of data" (click)="itemTapped($event, post)">
        <div style="background-image: url('{{getBackgroundStyle(post)}}')">
            <img src="{{getBackgroundStyle(post)}}">
```

Now, interestingly after building, the img tag works fine, while the div looses the style tag completely

Output in lab/browser:

```
<div class="singlePost">
    <div>
        <img src="http://theurl.com">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **attribute binding** instead:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ background-image: 'url(' + getBackgroundStyle(post) + ')' }"></div>
```

or

```
<div [style.background-image]="'url(' + getBackgroundStyle(post) + ')'"></div>
```

And the same should be done with the image element:

```
<img [src]="getBackgroundStyle(post)">
```